# retrofit map as body - how to post map with inner json object

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Retrofit2 how would i POST using a map json body that has inner json. Let me show you an example:

```
{
    "id_invoice": 1234,
    "action": "viewed",
    "data": {
        "id_object": 88,
        "id_store": 43,
        "type": "payment"
     }
}
```

Notice how the "data" JSON object has inner JSON.  How can I put all this into a map so, I can send it to retrofit using the following service endpoint:

```
public interface Api {
    @NonNull
    @POST("cart/payment")
    @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json"})
    Observable<ResponseBody> postPaymentEvent(@Body Map<String, Object> body);
}
```

I tried the following:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("id_object", 88);
json.put("id_store", 43);
json.put("type", "payment");
map.put("action", "view");
map.put("id_invoice", 1234);
map.put("data", json); //this is wrong. it creates the following response with a nameValuePairs field, which is not what i want:
```

> Body:

```
{
    "action": "page_view",
    "id_invoice": "1234",
    "data": {
        "nameValuePairs": {
            "id_object": 88,
            "id_store": 43,
            "type": "view"
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
 JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject();
            try {
                JSONObject parentJson = new JSONObject();

                dataJson.accumulate("id_object", 88);
                dataJson.accumulate("id_store", 43);
                dataJson.accumulate("type", "payment");


                parentJson.accumulate("id_invoice",1234);
                parentJson.accumulate("action","viewed");
                parentJson.put("data",dataJson);



                Log.d("Main Screen ",parentJson.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

It would generate this :

```
{
  "id_invoice": 1234,
  "action": "viewed",
  "data": {
    "id_object": 88,
    "id_store": 43,
    "type": "payment"
  }
}
```

Comment: i need it inside a Hashmap.

Comment: are you adding anything else in hash map ?

Comment: No. I just need to put that json in a map. Obviously i can use a class and gson. But was trying with map